# multiple user connecting to WCF at same time gives socket exception

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

when multiple users are connecting to WCF Service at the same time, we are getting socket Exception.

Error Message:
{"The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:09.9844000. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."}
Error code:10060

Comment: You should give more information with code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to increase timeout values?